# google compute engine how to recovery to 2 hours ago?

Tags: google-compute-engine, recovery, data-recovery

System is CentOS 7 i dont know why the /bin file missing, i cant login with ssh now.

The programs I spent a week making were all inside, no backups.

So this matter is very important to me.

Does anyone know how to restore data from a hard drive to a specific point in time?

Answer (score 0):

Taking [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots#creating_snapshots) will allow you to backup your data. Now, for the process of recovery you may have a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) which will guide you in creating an instance with a snapshot taken previously.

If you cannot login via SSH, you may also try to gain access by interacting with [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console). Here are the steps:

1). Activate the “Connect to serial console” button.

Go to VM instances, click on your VM, Edit, and active “enable connecting to serial ports” in the Remote access area and click on save.

2). Create a username and password.

Go to Vm instance, click on your Vm again, Edit, and fill up the custom metadata section with:

```
In key: startup-script
In value: 
#!/bin/bash 
sudo useradd -G sudo pamela
sudo echo 'pamela:pamela5' | chpasswd
```

(This is a script that creates a username : pamela and password: pamela5, which you are going to use later. Please use something else for security purposes)

3). Reboot for changes to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my snapshot information is 2018-10-01 version, I need to restore to 2018-11-03 11:00:00, is there any way to rescue?

Comment: Unfortunately, with no snapshot there is no backup,